# Calling a non static variable from another Script in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call overlapping in my first script, it works perfectly and gives the desired result when I use a debug.log within it's own script but it always returns false when I try to call it.

First Script:

```
public class AscendingSquareScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject ascendingBlock;
    SquareBlockScript squareBlockScript;
    float playerWidth;
    float playerHeight;
    float xPlacement;
    GameObject ascendingSquareHolder;
    public KeyCode moveDown;
    GameObject block;
    public SquareBlockScript value;
    void Start() {
        squareBlockScript = ascendingBlock.GetComponent<SquareBlockScript> () as SquareBlockScript;
        ascendingSquareHolder = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("AscendingSquareHolder");

        playerHeight = ascendingBlock.gameObject.renderer.bounds.size.y;
        playerWidth = ascendingBlock.gameObject.renderer.bounds.size.x;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            RandomNumberGenerator ();
            block = Instantiate (ascendingBlock) as GameObject;
            block.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f)).x + (playerWidth/2) + (playerWidth * xPlacement),  Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f)).y + playerHeight/2 + (playerHeight*i),0f);
            block.transform.parent = ascendingSquareHolder.transform;
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        if (ascendingBlock.GetComponent<SquareBlockScript> ().getOverLap ())
            Debug.Log ("It is currently working");

        if (Input.GetKeyUp (moveDown)) {
            ascendingSquareHolder.transform.position = ascendingSquareHolder.transform.position + new Vector3(0f, -playerHeight, 0f);
            GeneratingSquares();
        }
    }
}
```

Second Script:

```
public class SquareBlockScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool overLapping = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            overLapping = true;
            Debug.Log (overLapping + " it is");

        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "LowerBound") {
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            overLapping = false;
        }
    }
    public bool getOverLap(){
        return overLapping;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you do see the "True it is" message (from SquareBlockScript.OnTriggerEnter2D), but you don't get the "It is currently working" message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method on the instance not the "template" prefab.

```
public class AscendingSquareScript : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject ascendingBlock;
SquareBlockScript squareBlockScript;
float playerWidth;
float playerHeight;
float xPlacement;
GameObject ascendingSquareHolder;
public KeyCode moveDown;
GameObject block;
public SquareBlockScript value;
void Start() {
    squareBlockScript = ascendingBlock.GetComponent<SquareBlockScript> () as SquareBlockScript;
    ascendingSquareHolder = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("AscendingSquareHolder");

    playerHeight = ascendingBlock.gameObject.renderer.bounds.size.y;
    playerWidth = ascendingBlock.gameObject.renderer.bounds.size.x;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        RandomNumberGenerator ();
        block = Instantiate (ascendingBlock) as GameObject;
        block.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f)).x + (playerWidth/2) + (playerWidth * xPlacement),  Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f)).y + playerHeight/2 + (playerHeight*i),0f);
        block.transform.parent = ascendingSquareHolder.transform;
    }
}

void Update () {
    if (block.GetComponent<SquareBlockScript> ().getOverLap ())
        Debug.Log ("It is currently working");

    if (Input.GetKeyUp (moveDown)) {
        ascendingSquareHolder.transform.position = ascendingSquareHolder.transform.position + new Vector3(0f, -playerHeight, 0f);
        GeneratingSquares();
    }
}
}
```

so call .getOverLap () on block not ascendingBlock. But this will only work for the last instance assigned to block. You can't use the method on ascendingBlock as its only a template prefab used to create the instances.

Comment: Is there a way to make that same variable apply to multiple instances of it, instead of just the last?

Comment: You would have to put them in an array or a list while you instantiate them.